# About the use of être in the two sentences (conveying "What happened to you?")

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, conjugaison, questions

Which sentence is better for "What happened to you?"

From the FRENCH textbook "le nouveau taxi", leçon 30, there are two expressions:

> version old: Qu'est-ce qui vous êtes arrivé?

> version new: Qu'est-ce qui vous est  arrivé?

I have no idea about the differences between them. Please tell me more.

Comment: Those are now both the same. Is that how they appear in the French "textbook"??

Comment: @Lambie Not the same!

Comment: Ok, I see. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

**Yet another update taking into account the OP's new modifications...**

The former sentence is incorrect. The latter is the correct one. User @jlliagre provides a good explanation.

> Qu'est-ce qui vous est arrivé ? Ce qui m'arrivé...

Another option (rather formal) is

> Que vous est-il arrivé ?

To quote user @XouDo: *Due to the liaison, both sentences ''Qu'est-ce qui vous êtes arrivé'' and ''Qu'est ce qui vous est arrivé'' would sound the same. But the first one makes no sense.*

Comment: sorry for my mistakes. I've corrected the question.

Comment: Due to the liaison, both sentences **Qu'est-ce qui vous êtes arrivé* and *Qu'est ce qui vous est arrivé* would sound the same. But the first on makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct and means "What happened to you?" (Literally: "What is it what happened to you?")

The first sentence is deliberately fooling readers by using the otherwise correct phrase *vous êtes arrivé* (i.e. You arrived) in a sentence where the pronoun *vous* is actually not the subject of *être* but its complement.

As XouDo commented, both forms are pronounced the same way, or at least almost the same way.